# What model circuit breaker is this?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I live in an old 50 + year old house and it still has the original circuit breakers. I am trying to search for one that died, but don't know the model or even if they make these anymore. If any electricians out there can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

I haven't removed it (Kinda' scared to do so and get shocked), but here's a pic.
[image]
[image]

Here's [more pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqMaP.jpg) on the Fuse Box.

Comment: With something that old, and burnt, I'd call an electrician.

Comment: Is all of that white stuff spattered all over the inside of the breaker box part of several careless paint jobs? If it is not paint but instead some kind of corrosion inside or junk running down into the box due to some leak in the past then you would be well advised to replace the whole box with something a lot safer.

Comment: You also have to ask serious questions as to what caused that one circuit breaker to become so severely overheated like this one obviously was. The manner with which the plastic of the breaker appears to point to very high temperature operation over a long period of time. Such heat build up is likely to have also done some damage to the buss bar insulators under the breakers, cooked the insulation on adjacent wires and connected wires, and possibly even to the next door circuit breaker. I believe the evidence calls for the need of a complete safety inspection by a qualified professional.

Comment: I have been doing electrical work for 40 years and can't say I have ever seen this brand of breaker before. The size looks fairly large compared to an ITE/Murry style. I have to agree with Michael, That damage looks nasty and may have caused some other issues. I'd get a pro to take a look. Be careful!

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that by the time you are finished, the whole panel will be replaced.

Comment: I was writing down which breaker went to what Power Source and noticed that one of them (the burnt one) went nowhere. My guess is at some point, they changed over the wires to the second breaker in the top row. @MichaelKaras: Yeah, the white stuff IS crappy paint jobs. I just wanted to have a spare one in case another fails. Also, I really need to find a cover for this panel, which I don't have a clue where to start searching for one, before I end up replacing it all.

Comment: On closer inspection of the images, the breakers are marked as CU-AL which means they are for aluminum wiring.  Unless you know what you're doing, this is yet another reason to call an electrician.

Comment: Yes - Aluminum is also bad news in the Electrical world.  I'm not sure but I *think* that code requires that if you touch aluminum wire you are supposed to replace it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with aluminium wiring, except when you treat it like copper. Everything it's connected to has to be rated as CO/ALR, including wire nuts. You also have to use anti-oxidant paste (eg, Noalox) on all stripped ends. All of the trouble with AL wiring comes from it expanding and contracting as it heats and cools, which can lead to arcing. In older homes, just like copper it can be over-loaded as they didn't build houses for all the electrical gadgets we have today, but AL is usually a size bigger (eg, 15A circuit is 12AWG AL, while normally 14AWG CO). -Former owner of house with AL

Comment: It's made by either American Circuit Breaker Co., Federal Pacific Electric, Connecticut Breaker Co., Challenger, or Federal Pioneer.  If any of these companies still exist, they may be able to supply you with a replacement. If not, you'll have to find a used/refurbished replacement from eBay or a similar location.  It might be in your best interests to replace the entire panel with a more modern panel, instead of trying to locate a seemingly obsolete breaker.

Comment: @Tester: FPE had some serious issues in the 70's. Especially with Alu wires.

Answer (score 9):

While I think you'll be smart to hire an electrician and consider replacing the whole panel...

Circuit breaker boxes vary in style.  You have to buy the correct replacement breaker for your specific box.  To determine what you need, examine the box itself.  Somewhere on the box will be the name of the manufacturer.

Tip:  "Square D" is not it.  (Personal experience talking) - Square D MAKES breakers to fit numerous types of boxes.

If you can't immediately find the name of your panel maker, go to this link:
[Online site for buying circuit breakers](http://www.relectric.com/Circuit-Breakers/?mm_campaign=39f53512d73359a9ed1fb13bb4230c66&keyword=%2bcircuit%20%2bbreakers%20%2bmanufacturers&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=Circuit%20Breakers%20-%20New%20Structure&ad_type=b&gclid=CI2Lwcvt0LMCFUYw4AodXVQA3Qk)

They list a lot of manufacturers there - see if you can find yours.

Now again - because you yourself said you're scared to remove it - PLEASE DON'T.  This is potentially deadly work you're considering and if you don't know what you're doing, this is NOT a project you should learn using the trial and error method!!!

Update - after looking at the extra pics - your breaker box is by "American".  First manuf. on the list.  The labels on some of your breakers indicate it.

Comment: Why do you suggest replacing the whole panel? I love new and shiny as much as any geek, but I know I sometimes replace when it's not needed.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think your panel is discontinued and replacement parts will get harder to find.  But you should consult with an electrician on that.

Comment: @JayBazuzi -- Stab-Loks (yes, all of 'em) need to be melted in a blast furnace; replacement parts aren't going to be any safer than the original in this case.

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR: If you haven't incinerated yet, ***replace that panel as soon as possible, if not sooner!!!***

It looks like your panel may have been an archaic piece of equipment (fuse box?!) at some point which someone (illegally!) gutted and replaced with the guts of a FPE Stab-Lok panel.  Sadly, what they did is replace old, but somewhat-functional service equipment with [*total garbage*](http://inspectapedia.com/fpe/FPE_Hazards_121220.pdf) that is liable to not do its job whatsoever when called upon.  Yes -- these breakers, especially the two-pole types, are known to consistently fail to meet trip curves, and the two-pole versions are susceptible to an internal mechanical jam that turns them into fancy jumper leads.

P.S. the labels on the breakers are a dead giveaway -- one of them states "Stab-Lok" on it in somewhat messed up letters, and both of them have visible Type NA markings on them; unlike say a BR breaker (which fits several different makes of panels), the type NA is only compatible with FPE Stab-Lok panels.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is actually staring you in the face under all that paint: Electri-Center. These are, in theory, Seimens breakers. (I say in theory because the box looks like someone's taken a hacksaw to it, which means they may have replaced the guts with some other brand of hardware.) They should be available at Home Depot. Shut off the mains, remove the bad breaker, take it in to Home Depot and make sure that you match them. Alternately, take it to an electrical distributor and they'll be able to match it.

However, I would STRONGLY urge you to hire an electrician and have them evaluate the condition of the panel because of a few of the things that I see inside the box. First of all, there are wire 'colors' that mean specific things. What I'm seeing is a red wire and a green wire going into the hot side of some of these breakers. Red is 'meh' but not 'right'; it should only be used for the switch leg of a circuit but it's OK for it to be 'hot'. Green generally means ground and anyone working on the far end of that cable is going to get a surprise unless they're using a non-contact voltage sensor. There are distinct signs of hackery and/or overloading and/or age-induced overloading on this panel, and with that plus the aluminum wiring and the age of these breakers, I would be extremely leery of just replacing the breaker and assuming that it will be fine.

Comment: Not only do red and green wires not belong connected to breakers, they are far too small to carry 30 amp current as copper, even less so if aluminum. Yikes! This is a good way to start a fire. +100 for electrician evaluating the whole panel.

Comment: I didn't even catch that, bcworkz... thanks! I was too busy wincing at the rest of the panel.

Comment: Is a 220v circuit an exception to the "no red in the panel" rule?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - Yeah. But that didn't look like a 220v circuit to me, especially not on 12 ga al.

Comment: Yeah - not to mention they're not ganged together, which if they were 220v they should be.

Comment: The green one actually goes to the Water heater 110V (just one outlet) and the red one goes to the washing machine. I guess those were added later.

Comment: Ick ick ick. Get a professional in there: one skilled in old work.  Also note the complete lack of proper box entry on the green-yet-hot line.  I love repairing old stuff: this does not qualify.  Trash it.

Comment: This panel looks like a Frankenstein hack job -- and worse yet, those are *NOT*, I repeat, ***NOT***!!!! Siemens breakers in there!